# Is there, or could anyone make a tiny 1 to 2 USB-C "splitter" hub that only contains a female USB-C-PD port and a female USB-C data port?

Tags: usb, hub, power, adapter, splitters

It still amazes me that it's almost the end of 2018 and still no one seems to have been able to, to my knowledge, find or create such a device. I did however gather some more information, so here I go.

To clarify what the adapter should be able to do:

The USB-C male port is for the host device, aka a phone.

The USB-C-PD female port is for power. So it could be connected to a wall adapter with a C-C cable and provide power to the host device (and maybe also for the second device).

The USB-C data female port is for USB devices that can be connected to the host device, aka a flashdrive, mouse or 3.5mm dongle (with DAC).

For reference, I own a USB-C hub that does all these things, however it's very large (especially for a phone) since besides these ports it also packs in an extra USB-C port and two USB-A 3.1 ports. I'm talking about the Aukey CB-C48
https://www.aukey.life/products/cbc48-usb-c-hub-2-port-usb-3-0-2-port-usb-c-1-port-usb-c-with-pd. This device existing, shows that the idea of a "splitter" is actually possible, just never done before (to my knowledge).

The size I'm looking for is around this size: [image: this size]
(Don't be fooled by its appearance, the adapter in the picture only wires the lines regarding power one way, while it wires the lines for Analog-Audio-over-USB-C the other way, which is great, if you have a phone with a DAC and only want to use it for headphones but not for anything else.)

Another option would be this form factor: https://hackaday.io/project/26263-pd-buddy-wye. (This one works the other way around, allowing your phone to fast-charge over PD from a charger and connect to a PC via USB. It doesn't allow the phone to be the host.)

Finally I found another adapter of which I do not know whether it works: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07KSZMG5J?pf_rd_p=1581d9f4-062f-453c-b69e-0f3e00ba2652&pf_rd_r=SMDQYBNA8X75H9EGVK16](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07KSZMG5J). These types of adapters have a DAC inside them,thus enabling phones without a DAC to connect to USB-C headphones (or dongles) without DAC. At least that's what I've gathered from the descriptions. However, I don't know if the port can also be used for other USB peripherals. The seller did tell me it didn't work with mice/flashdrives, but it did work with the 3.5mm dongle from Google, which is odd, because it does have a DAC inside and thus is a completely normal USB peripheral, just like a mouse for instance. I did order one to test what's true and what isn't about these. When mine arrives, I'll update the post.

Edit 1: Another item I found was the Cusby, a failed indiegogo campain: https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/cusby-first-usb-c-modular-expandable-adapter and http://www.cusby.com/. In particular their "power port" module does exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately they've been silent for 3 years now, so yeah...

So if anyone finds anything, please let me know and if anyone has the capacity to design and build such an adapter also let me know. I really hope it can be realized!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well let me be the one to answer my own question. I found a working adapter! It allows to pd charge my phone and have a USB c port left for other peripherals.

This adapter https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/2-in-1-Snelle-Lading-Headset-Adapter-Type-C-USB-C-3-5mm-Digitale-Audio-Kabel/32961645430.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.4b6a4c4d82wJiw [1]
from AliExpress is advertised as a USB C splitter just like the ones on Amazon, but on the contrary it never mentions having a DAC like the ones on Amazon. What it does mention is working with the Pixel phones and I can confirm that! Not only does it work for the Google 3.5mm dongle, but it also works for a mouse and USB flash drive I tried. 
I'm sure there are some on Amazon working the same way (as they often re-sell Chinese stock) but I haven't tried any of those as they were more expensive.

I also haven't tried it on other devices like a Chromebook but I assume it works the same for all USB 3.1 devices (like the pixel 2xl). Whether USB alternative mode is supported for displays I cannot test currently.

Edit: I just tried the adapter with a Oneplus 6T (USB 2.0 with analog audio over USB) and it only works one port at a time. And analog audio doesn't work. This is quite expected because of the broken and old spec Oneplus uses and the lack of audio over usb c wires in the adapter.

Edit: part number is 4NB900424-B if the link stops working

[1]: http://€ 8,92  27%OFF | 2 in 1 Fast Charge Headset Adapter Type-C USB-C 3.5mm Digital Audio Cable Converter For iPad Pro Google HTC Huawei Essential Mac
 https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/2-in-1-Snelle-Lading-Headset-Adapter-Type-C-USB-C-3-5mm-Digitale-Audio-Kabel/32961645430.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.4b6a4c4d82wJiw

Answer (score 3):

These small splitters should be avoided at all costs. As Benson Leung's [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/UsbCHardware/comments/emf9yk/psa_avoid_usbc_ysplit_cables_or_adapters_evil/) explains

> There are no active components inside. It bridges many pins (power, data, gnd, cc) among the three USB-C connectors). What this means is that your phone or laptop can negotiated much higher voltage than vSafe5V, and that will just magically show up on the other USB-C receptacle.
>
> If the other USB-C receptacle has a headphone or a USB-C thumbdrive or a USB-C Yubikey that is only 5V tolerant, it will be destroyed.

A later [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/UsbCHardware/comments/gpmdz7/can_i_use_a_usbc_hub_to_connect_usb_mousekeyboard/fro2cu4/) by someone much less famous but nonetheless correct:

> A proper adapter would need a buck converter for 5V, a power switch on the downstream data port, and two USB PD interfaces with good firmware that implements proper derating. Essentially a full blown charge-through hub.

Comment: Correct. However, the adapter I used to answer my own question is a full blown hub I believe. It's just small, but way bigger than the adapters I found in my post (which indeed should be avoided as they just rewire pins instead of interfacing with them).

Comment: Could you edit your answer noting you tested with a charger and it worked?